# Invisible differences in XML files - breaking self-made XML parser

Tags: c#, c++, xml, visual-studio-2012

I have two programs that interact with an  well-defined XML file.  The first program (Model) reads it in, parses it, and uses content from the file to direct the running of a model.  The second program (Controller) opens up and rewrites the XML file, allowing different settings to be run in the Model.

Model is written in C++, worked with in VS2010 and VS2012, has no GUI, and uses a home-made (is this the correct term?) XML parser that has worked for many years without fail - I just checked the SVN for revisions to the files that make it up - nothing since 2013.  Controller is written in C#, in VS2012, with a GUI that has drop downs that set the content of the XML file, and uses the [XmlDocument class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-3) to read in, edit, and print out the XML file .

Suddenly, the Controller no longer spits out XML files that can be read by Model.  When Model tries to read the XML file, the first character it encounters it reads as '-17'.  AS far as I have been able to tell this means that it doesn't recognize it as an UTF-8 character.  This cause model to cout the error and then crash.  Older XML file (which looks identical to the ones written by Controller) reads in fine.

Below are examples of the files - ignore the content inside the elements please.  Some of you may say that the content might be causing the problem, but I've checked it again and again, and it is correct.  And if the content mattered, why would the parser in Model fail at the very first character ('<' = '-17') when reading in the XmlDocument created file?

Older file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Config>
<Mode value="false" Id="Modeflag" />
<Timestep OutputTimestep="Hourly"  CalibrationTimestep="Houry" />
<InitialInput SubCatchmentNumber="1" ModelCalibration="true" SnowSimulation="false" VegSimulation="Method 1" CatchmentNumber="1" FractionalCatchmentArea="1" />
<InputResource Name="All" Location="C:\AutoRun_Newest\AutoRun" Id="Directory" />
<SimulationScheme SchemeForCatchmentNo="8" Infiltration="true" ChannelRouting="false" Saturation="true" TopographicIndex="true" KDecayWithSoilDepthExp="false" SoilTopoIndex="false" KDecayInPower="true" />
<SnowInput InputCatchmentNumber="1" TempIndexMethod_Hourly="false" RadiationTempIndex_With_SnowInterception="true" EnergyBudgetMethod_With_SnowInterception="false" />
<SnowInputResource Name="All" Location="C:\AutoRun_Newest\AutoRun" Id="SnowDirectory" />
<OutputDirectory Location="C:\AutoRun_Newest\Inputs\Output_Timestamp_07012015215112" Name="Toronto_Output" />
</Config>
```

Newer file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Config>
  <Mode value="false" Id="Modeflag" />
  <Timestep OutputTimestep="Hourly" CalibrationTimestep="Hourly" />
  <InitialInput SubCatchmentNumber="1" ModelCalibration="true" SnowSimulation="false" VegSimulation="Method 1" CatchmentNumber="1" FractionalCatchmentArea="1" />
  <InputResource Name="All" Location="C:\AutoRun_Newest\AutoRun" Id="Directory" />
  <SimulationScheme SchemeForCatchmentNo="8" Infiltration="true" ChannelRouting="false" Saturation="true" TopographicIndex="true" KDecayWithSoilDepthExp="false" SoilTopoIndex="false" KDecayInPower="true" />
  <SnowInput InputCatchmentNumber="1" TempIndexMethod_Hourly="false" RadiationTempIndex_With_SnowInterception="true" EnergyBudgetMethod_With_SnowInterception="false" />
  <SnowInputResource Name="All" Location="C:\AutoRun_Newest\AutoRun" Id="SnowDirectory" />
  <OutputDirectory Location="C:\AutoRun_Newest\Inputs\Output_Timestamp_07012015215112" Name="Toronto_Output" />
</Config>
```

Adding or taking away the indentation (proper formatting by the XmlDocument class in C#) changes nothing about the behavior of Model.

These files are visually identical, and I can see no odd characters or spacing.  What invisible objects/forces/characters or other settings could be causing this new bug?

Is there some background encoding that the XML document class enforces that is new to my home made parser?

Comment: You are seeing a UTF-8 [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) - a byte sequence `EF BB BF`. `0xEF == -17` when interpreted as a `signed char`. There's probably some way to tell `XmlDocument` not to emit a BOM.

Comment: Okay, so what do I do?  I can look into that, but any quick tips?  And what could have caused this sudden change - this was working several weeks ago (last major change to Model), but now when trying to test out a new change to Model it doesn't work......

Comment: If you encounter the BOM, skip over it (3 bytes), and make sure you treat the rest of the file as UTF-8 encoded (which is what the `encoding` tag in the header is meant to indicate anyway).

Comment: Yes, you guys are correct - just verified the encoding in Notepad++.  Can't believe I didn't think to do that.  Know I just have to alter my Controller C# code to remove the BOM in printing out the altered XML.

Comment: You need to be aware that you can be using a home-made XML parser successfully for years and it will work just fine so long as you don't take it outside its comfort zone. Present it with something it hasn't seen before, like a BOM, or a new encoding, or spaces around the "=" sign in an attribute, or processing instructions in the external subset of the DTD, and it's very likely to break. By using homebrew software instead of a widely deployed off the shelf parser, you are asking for this kind of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a byte order mark (BOM) at the start of the file.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

The BOM is Unicode character U+FEFF, or in UTF-8 the bytes 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF.  0xEF is -17 if you reinterpret it as a signed byte.  Many Windows tools in particular will put a BOM at the start of the file if you save it.